# Simple double integral in polar coordinates' exercise (changing it to polar coordinates)

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

I'm solving one of Stewart's Calculus exercises and I disagree with the sketch made in the mark scheme, even though the answer I got was the same:

(exercise 31)

[image]

This is my sketch:

[image]

And this is the mark scheme:

[image]

Which one is correct?

Comment: The marking scheme. Note that the range of $y$ is from $0$ to $1$,

Comment: Just to add, the first integral done is $dx$ so $y=x$ should be the left hand side boundary. However your sketch has $x=0$ as the left hand side boundary.

Comment: You fix a $y$ in the outer integral (loosely speaking), and then in the inner integral, $x$ ranges from $x=y$ to $x=\sqrt{2-y^2}$. It looks like the provided solution is correct.

Comment: I see it now. Thank you!

Comment: And the region you drew is $0 \leq x \leq  y$ for $0 \leq y \leq 1$ and $0 \leq x \leq \sqrt{2-y^2}$ for $1 \leq y \leq \sqrt2$.